# Fetch data from Excel File

Tags: node.js, json, database

I am new to the coding scene and I am not well experienced at all in code but I am getting into it. My focus is currently on node and mongoDB and I was given a question assignment by one of my experienced friends to do but I do not seem to understand it exactly. Does this application page expect me to use a database to convert the excel file to json then use it with my preferred database or does it want me to directly use node to display an excel file I can edit through a browser.[Application page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN3wG.png)

I am confused as it states that I should use these to make the website and does not include any mention of a database [Requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOJp7.png)

What should I be able to do exactly?